# Fold and select the definition of a function in python?

Tags: python, ide

In python mode (the one that Emacs uses to open python script by default), can I fold the definition of a function?

How can I quickly select the entire definition of a function? (so that I can copy and paste)

If not, which python package/IDE shall I install in emacs? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For folding, I use [Hideshow mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html) (built-in) with [Hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) like this:

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "M-F")
 (defhydra hydra-fold (global-map "M-F")
   "Fold"
   ("h" hs-hide-all "hide all")
   ("s" hs-show-all "show all")
   ("f" hs-toggle-hiding "toggle")))
```

To mark the current function, press `C-M-h` to run `mark-defun`.

These work for nearly any language.